# PHP - handling URL that automatically download file

Tags: php, file, url, download, e-commerce

I'm working on e-shop project and I need to handle URL. I never worked with URL like that. I can't post URL there, because of the private data that are included in. But it is URL that is not going open a tab in browser, because it automatically download a file(in chrome) and in firefox it only ask to download. No tab opened. I did some research, but I didnt find any URL handling like this.

Here a edited example of how the URL looks:

https://domain.cz/api/export?token=121212121212121212

It is some kind of API, but my question is: How I can handle this type of URL in PHP? I want to save that file or even better - get the file contents directly to variable in code.

Thanks for you help
Confused developer

Comment: Using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) should allow you to do what you want, either saving the file or getting it into a variable.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not works.